pass column name as string to function and make the new column inside of function in R
I currently need to create 26 new columns based on 26*2 other columns in my dataframe in R. I don't think using mutate is an option because the function is a little bit complicated. An example dataframe with fewer columns is
test_dat <- tibble(item1.y=c(1,3,2),item1.x=c(0,3,3),item2.y=c(3,1,4),item2.x=c(3,3,3),item3.y=c(2,4,1),item3.x=c(1,3,2))


I need to generate 3 new columns based on the current columns. Right now, the function I have written to try to accomplish what I need is:
normalized_change <- function(df,post,pre,newcol){
  df <- df %>% add_column(newcol = NA)
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(post[i]>pre[i]){
      df$newcol[i] <- (post[i]-pre[i])/(4-pre[i])
    }
    if(post[i]==pre[i]){
      df$newcol[i] <- 0
    }
    if(post[i]<pre[i]){
      df$newcol[i] <- (post[i]-pre[i])/pre[i]
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

In order to achieve the desired result, I will have to call the function a total of 3 times, once for each new column I need to generate.
test_dat <- normalized_change(test_dat,test_dat$item1.y,test_dat$item1.x,newcol="norm_change1")
test_dat <- normalized_change(test_dat,test_dat$item2.y,test_dat$item2.x,newcol="norm_change2")
test_dat <- normalized_change(test_dat,test_dat$item3.y,test_dat$item3.x,newcol="norm_change3")

My final test_dat should like like:
tibble(item1.y=c(1,3,2),
       item1.x=c(0,3,3),
       item2.y=c(3,1,4),
       item2.x=c(3,3,3),
       item3.y=c(2,4,1),
       item3.x=c(1,3,2),
       norm_change1=c(0.25,0,-0.33),
       norm_change2=c(0,-0.66,1),
       norm_change3=c(0.33,1,-0.5)
)

However, the issue is that whenever I run the function normalized_change, the new column is given the name newcol instead of "norm_change1." In my actual data, I will have to make 26 new columns based on 26*2 current columns. If anyone can give advice on how I can make the function actually generate a column with my preferred name, that would be great. However, if anyone has a more efficient way of doing this that wouldn't require me calling my function 26 times, that would be even better!
I have tried a number of different things. Mutate functions don't work because I don't think they can accept such a complicated function. In order to make my current function work, I have tried things like forcing newcol to be a character which didn't work.

Here I convert your data into a tidy/long format and apply your function in a simple case_when statement. It's likely that additional work on your data will be easier in a long format (especially plotting or modeling, but also additional transformation), so I would suggest keeping it that way. However, if you do want to convert it back to the original wide format this shows how to do that as well:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

long_result = test_dat |>
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-row_id, names_pattern = c("(pre|post)([\\d])"), names_to = c("prepost", "i")) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = prepost, values_from = value) |>
  mutate(
    norm_change = case_when(
      post > pre ~ (post - pre) / (4 - pre),
      post == pre ~ 0,
      post < pre ~ (post - pre) / pre
    ) 
  )
long_result
# # A tibble: 9 × 5
#   row_id i      post   pre norm_change
#    <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1      1 1         1     0       0.25 
# 2      1 2         3     3       0    
# 3      1 3         2     1       0.333
# 4      2 1         3     3       0    
# 5      2 2         1     3      -0.667
# 6      2 3         4     3       1    
# 7      3 1         2     3      -0.333
# 8      3 2         4     3       1    
# 9      3 3         1     2      -0.5  

long_result |>
  pivot_longer(c(post, pre, norm_change)) |>
  unite(colname, name, i, sep = "") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = colname, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 3 × 10
#   row_id post1  pre1 norm_change1 post2  pre2 norm_change2 post3  pre3 norm_change3
#    <int> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1      1     1     0        0.25      3     3        0         2     1        0.333
# 2      2     3     3        0         1     3       -0.667     4     3        1    
# 3      3     2     3       -0.333     4     3        1         1     2       -0.5  


I realized I mistakenly uploaded test data with the incorrect column names. I updated the column names in my original post to reflect this. I tried setting names_pattern equal to c("(x|y)(\d)") and c("(\W.*)(\d)") and neither case worked.

If there's a period separating the components that's even easier. You can use names_sep = "\\." instead of the names_pattern argument.

Or you could still use names_pattern, I would try something like (.*)\\.(.*).

Using cur_column and get in across and simplifying your function using case_when you could do:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

normalized_change <- function(post, pre) {
  case_when(
    post > pre ~ (post - pre) / (4 - pre),
    post < pre ~ (post - pre) / pre,
    .default = 0
  )
}

tibble(
  post1 = c(1, 3, 2), pre1 = c(0, 3, 3), post2 = c(3, 1, 4),
  pre2 = c(3, 3, 3), post3 = c(2, 4, 1), pre3 = c(1, 3, 2)
) |>
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("post"),
      ~ normalized_change(.x, get(gsub("post", "pre", cur_column()))),
      .names = "norm_change{gsub('post', '', .col)}"
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 9
#>   post1  pre1 post2  pre2 post3  pre3 norm_change1 norm_change2 norm_change3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1     1     0     3     3     2     1        0.25         0            0.333
#> 2     3     3     1     3     4     3        0           -0.667        1    
#> 3     2     3     4     3     1     2       -0.333        1           -0.5


You can try
cbind(
    df,
    list2DF(
        lapply(
            split.default(df, paste0("norm_change", sub("^\\D+", "", names(df)))),
            function(x) (x[[1]] - x[[2]]) / ifelse(x[[1]] > x[[2]], 4 - x[[2]], x[[2]])
        )
    )
)

which gives
  post1 pre1 post2 pre2 post3 pre3 norm_change1 norm_change2 norm_change3
1     1    0     3    3     2    1    0.2500000    0.0000000    0.3333333
2     3    3     1    3     4    3    0.0000000   -0.6666667    1.0000000
3     2    3     4    3     1    2   -0.3333333    1.0000000   -0.5000000

